# Incongruency between Python and R interpretation of C code

Tags: python, r, c

I am working on a project that translates R code into Python, but for some segments the original R code references C code functions.

Here is the function of the underlying C code.

```
void SurvBeranKernel(
    double *const time2,
    int *const status,
    double *const time1,
    int *const delta,
    const int *const len,
    const double *const t2,
    const double *const t1,
    const double *const lambda,
    const char *const *const kernel,
    double *const surv)
    

{   
    double weights[*len];
    WeightsKernel(time1, len, t1, lambda, kernel, weights); // compute kernel weights
    WeightedKaplanMeierValueSort(time2, status, weights, delta, len, t2, surv); // compute conditional survival probability
    return;
} // SurvBeranKernel
```

As you can see it includes other functions, I can add more C code or share a whole file if necessary.

Here's the original R code

```
time <- c(58.72131, 41.90164, 16.22951, 145.44262, 10.55738, 54.95082, 196.45902, 194.03279, 20.95082, 20.00000)
status <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
covariate <- c(6.364198, 4.911329, 6.526469, 4.774352, 5.587983, 6.897707, 3.045640, 6.167040, 5.187449, 6.407494)
delta <- rep(1, 10)
len <- 10
y <- 196.459
x <- 3.04564
bw <- 0.1
kernel <- 'gaussian'

res <- .C("SurvBeranKernel", as.double(time), as.integer(status), 
          as.double(covariate), as.integer(delta), as.integer(len), 
          as.double(y), as.double(x), as.double(bw), as.character(kernel), 
          p = as.double(1))$p
```

The result is

```
1
```

Here's the Python code I wrote

```
from ctypes import *

#Importing shared C object

survivalBIV = CDLL('survivalBIV.so')

survBeranKernel = survivalBIV.SurvBeranKernel
survBeranKernel.argtypes = (POINTER(c_double), POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_double),
                            POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_int), POINTER(c_double),
                            POINTER(c_double),POINTER(c_double),
                            POINTER(c_wchar_p), POINTER(c_double))
survBeranKernel.restype = None

def do_SurvBeranKernel_using_c_test():

    '''double *const time2,
    int *const status,
    double *const time1,
    int *const delta,
    const int *const len,
    const double *const t2,
    const double *const t1,
    const double *const lambda,
    const char *const *const kernel,
    double *const surv'''

    """Call C function to calculate squares"""

    # Declaring the variables
    time = [58.72131, 41.90164, 16.22951, 145.44262, 10.55738, 54.95082, 196.45902, 194.03279, 20.95082, 20.00000] #time2 variable in C
    status = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
    covariate = [6.364198, 4.911329, 6.526469, 4.774352, 5.587983, 6.897707, 3.045640, 6.167040, 5.187449, 6.407494]  #time1 variable in C
    delta = [1]*10
    n = 10 # len variable in C
    y = 196.459 #t2 variable in C
    x = 3.04564 #t1 variable in C
    bw = 0.1 #lambda variable in C
    kernel = 'gaussian'
    surv = 1


    #Converting variables to format readable to C
    c_arr_time = (c_double * n)(*time)
    c_arr_status = (c_int * n)(*status)
    c_arr_covariate = (c_double * n)(*covariate)
    c_arr_delta = (c_int * n)(*delta)
    c_int_len = c_int(10)
    c_float_t2 = c_double(y)
    c_float_t1 = c_double(x)
    c_float_lambda = c_double(bw)
    c_str_kernel = c_wchar_p(kernel)
    c_float_surv = c_double(surv)


    survBeranKernel(c_arr_time, c_arr_status, c_arr_covariate, c_arr_delta, c_int_len,
                    c_float_t2, c_float_t1, byref(c_float_lambda), byref(c_str_kernel), byref(c_float_surv))

    # Add .value to extract the Python object.
    return c_float_surv.value


res_test = do_SurvBeranKernel_using_c_test()

print(res_test)
```

The result is

```
0.44529294044495793
```

I can't figure out where the discrepancy comes from.

Comment: Hard to know for sure but in r a character vector is not exactly the same as a const char *

Comment: Hi Hugh! What do you mean? How can I correct it? I am really bad with C.

Comment: `POINTER(c_wchar_p)` should most likely be `POINTER(c_char_p)`. `wchar_t*` is a wide character (Unicode) string while the C function is expecting an ANSI string (`char *`). Also, `lambda` is a pointer passed with `byref()`, which makes it a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: It’s a bit too much for a comment, but you have to use CHAR to go from r to c. Without seeing the full source I have no idea if this has been done. I recommend the .Call interface too, even if the .C might work